# Shallow array equals in javascript

Tags: javascript

Are there any improvements that can be made on the following to check the equality of two arrays in javascript?

```js
"use strict"
function main(arr1, arr2) {
    if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
        return false;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true;
}
const tests = [
  [[1,2],[1,2]],
  [[1],[1,2]],
  [[1,2],[1]],
  [[1,2],[3,4]],
  [[],[]]
]
for (const [arr1, arr2] of tests) {
  let res = main(arr1, arr2);
  console.log(arr1, arr2, res);
}
```

Comment: You should know to ask a question like this at [codereview.SE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is an improvement, but you could make it shorter:

```js
"use strict"

function main(arr1, arr2) {
    return (
      arr1.length === arr2.length
      && arr1.every((v, i) => arr2[i] === v)
    );
}

const tests = [
  [[1,2],[1,2]],
  [[1],[1,2]],
  [[1,2],[1]],
  [[1,2],[3,4]],
  [[],[]]
]
for (const [arr1, arr2] of tests) {
  let res = main(arr1, arr2);
  console.log(arr1, arr2, res);
}
```

Comment: which of the two formats do you think is preferable? The `for` loop or using `every`? Or it's just a matter of taste?

Comment: I personally strongly prefer array iteration methods over for loops, but it's just an aesthetic thing. It's also possible there's a performance difference (due to the overhead for the inline function) but unless you're doing very large arrays it's not going to matter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no further improvement in terms of the algorithm used to check array equality, AFAIK.